# How to do correctly multiple calls to firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

Situation:

I have to get file download url, and I have an array of file names. So I need to call multiple time to firebase storage to get file url and create new array of file's url's.

What I did:

I map my array of file names and call to firebase storage each time. And create `Promise.all` to collect all results and set to state.

My code:

```
let getLinks = arr.map( async obj => {
            return await storageRef.child(`agencies/${agencyData.id}/users-forms-uploads/${docId}/${obj.upload}`)
                .getDownloadURL()
                .then(url => ({
                            id: obj.id,
                            url
                }))
        })


        Promise.all([getLinks])
        .then((res) => {
            setDocumentsLinks(res)
        })
```

What I got:

As result I got array of promises instead array of objects which contains `id` and `url`
[image: Array of primises]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just a simple syntax error as you shouldn't wrap `getLinks` in an array when passing it to `Promise.all()`.

```
let getLinks = arr.map(/* ... */)
// getLinks is a Promise<{id: string, url: string}>[]
```

```
Promise.all([getLinks]) // feeding Promise.all() an array of an array of Promises
  .then(/* ... */);
```

should be

```
Promise.all(getLinks) // feeding Promise.all() an array of Promises
  .then(/* ... */);
```